# Proof of Hitting-time theorem in branching processes

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

I want to understand theorem 5.21 (page 224) in [this link](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~roch/mdp/roch-mdp-chap5.pdf) and here is where I don't understand: $$
\{W = t\} = \{t \text{ is the first ladder index in }R_1, \dots, R_t\},$$
i.e. $\{R_t = 1, R_1 < 1, \dots, R_{t-1} < 1\}$.

And if anyone can offer easier ways to prove it, it would be great to hear your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the proof of Theorem 5.21 (page 224) in the notes at your link, we find the definitions 
$R_i:=1-S_i$, with $R_0:=0$. By Lemma 5.17 and the three-line display on page 221 of those notes, 
$$W=\tau_0=\inf\{t\ge0\colon S_t=0\},$$
whence 
$$W=\tau_0=\inf\{t\ge0\colon R_t=1\}.$$
Thus,
$$W=t\iff R_1<1,\dots,R_{t-1}<1,R_t = 1,$$
as claimed.

Comment: Can you also explain how $\tau_0 = \inf\{t \geq 0 : S_t = 0\}$ works only regarding branching process? The notes explains in regard to random walk and it is hard to relate with branching process for me. 

Or would it be better to ask another question? Thank you in advance!

Comment: In case that my question was not clear enough. I want to know what $S_n$ means in branching process where $S_n = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - 1)$ where $X_i$ is an offspring process and why $\tau_0 = \inf\{t \geq 0 : S_t = 0\}$. Thank you!

Comment: @MathislikeFriday : This additional question should indeed be posted separately.